# Python while loop number guessing game with limited guesses

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, and-operator

For a class assignment, I'm trying to make a number guessing game in which the user decides the answer and the number of guesses and then guesses the number within those limited number of turns. I'm supposed to use a while loop with an and operator, and can't use break. However, my issue is that I'm not sure how to format the program so that when the maximum number of turns is reached the program doesn't print hints (higher/lower), but rather only tells you you've lost/what the answer was. **It doesn't work specifically if I choose to make the max number of guesses 1.** Instead of just printing " You lose; the number was __", it also prints a hint as well. This is my best attempt that comes close to doing everything that this program is supposed to do. What am I doing wrong?

```
answer = int(input("What should the answer be? "))
guesses = int(input("How many guesses? "))

guess_count = 0
guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
guess_count += 1
if answer < guess:
    print("The number is lower than that.")
elif answer > guess:
    print("The number is higher than that")

while guess != answer and guess_count < guesses:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
    guess_count += 1
    if answer < guess:
        print("The number is lower than that.")
    elif answer > guess:
        print("The number is higher than that")

if guess_count >= guesses and guess != answer:
    print("You lose; the number was " + str(answer) + ".")
if guess == answer:
    print("You win!")
```

Comment: This seems to work fine for me

Comment: I'm confused why you think it is wrong. This runs for me, and does what I *think* you were trying to do?

Comment: You might try either nesting your hints inside a max guesses check or add an and condition to each hint requiring guess tries to be less than max guesses

Comment: @Reedinationer To be more precise, It doesn't work specifically if I choose to make the max number of guesses 1. Instead of just printing " You lose; the number was __", it also prints a hint as well.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere Isn't the condition in the while loop (guess_count < guesses) supposed to make sure that this loop only runs when the guess tries are less than the max guesses?

Comment: @exc22 a while loop will finish the loop it is on after the run condition becomes false. It is only when it goes to run the **next** loop that it realizes the condition is false and exits by not running that next loop.

Comment: @Reedinationer Oh, okay thank you so much!

Comment: @exc22 No problem! It sounds like a typical "off by one" error. Maybe you could try `while guess != answer and guess_count < guesses - 1:` to subtract this last run of the loop you don't want?

Comment: @exc22, you'll need to handle both places where you print the hints - each place you increment the counter.

Comment: @Reedinationer Just tried it and it doesn't work for some reason. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Did you try nesting the hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
answer = int(input("What should the answer be? "))
guesses = int(input("How many guesses? "))
guess_count = 1
guess_correct = False

while guess_correct is False:
    if guess_count < guesses:
        guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
        if answer < guess:
            print("The number is lower than that.")
        elif answer > guess:
            print("The number is higher than that")
        else:  # answer == guess
            print("You win!")
            break
        guess_count += 1
    elif guess_count == guesses:
        guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
        if guess != answer:
            print("You lose; the number was " + str(answer) + ".")
        if guess == answer:
            print("You win!")
        break
```

It's very similar to your program, but has a couple `break` statements in there. This tells Python to immediately stop execution of that loop and go to the next block of code (nothing in this case). In this way you don't have to wait for the program to evaluate the conditions you specify for your `while` loop before starting the next loop. If this helped solve your problem, it'd be great of you to click the checkmark by my post